# Python sending package through wrong interface

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi that is both connected to the internet via Wlan and a local device via Ethernet. So it has two IPs; one for each endpoint.

This is how it looks like simplified when running `ifconfig`; with different IPs for privacy

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
        inet 189.168.200.110  netmask 0.0.0.0  broadcast 255.255.255.255 
    
 
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
        inet 189.168.201.79  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

This is the code that python is using to send a message to the device through the Ethernet with that gateway's ip

```
    TCP_PORT = 3001
    SERVER_IP_AD = "189.168.200.110"
    CLIENT_IP_AD = "189.168.200.155"
    BROADCAST_IP = "255.255.255.255"

    def sendMessage(self, file_path, client_ip=CLIENT_IP_AD):
        print('message en route')
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind((self.SERVER_IP_AD, 0))
        s.connect((client_ip, self.TCP_PORT)) #**ERROR IS HERE**

        MESSAGE = self.openFile(file_path)
        s.send(MESSAGE.encode())
        data = s.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)
        s.close()
        return data
```

Using wireshark I can see that the package is being sent through the Wlan interface instead of the Ethernet interface with the correct IP source and IP destination.

How do I tell python to use the correct interface when sending out the package?

Comment: You've kind-of got your server and client roles mixed up here. You absolutely should *first* read the [python socket HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html). I think it will help make some things clearer to you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you unplug the Ethernet cable from the wlan0 device's port, and then run your programs?  Does the data get to the local device then?

Comment: If I shut down wifi on the raspberry Pi it does go to the intended device, but then I loose internet connection which is needed for another part

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can establish Tcp connection with Ethernet, cause there isn't shaking hands by Ethernet
And, you shouldn't use s.bind() and s.connect() at the same time. Because the former is for UDP client, and the later is for TCP client. Have a try with only s.bind().

Comment: It is possible to send a shake of hands through Ethernet since it is only a physical transport layer and does not restrict what is being sent at all. 

Even if it somehow did I have been able to do it with the same code on Windows, the only problem here is that on Linux it is being sent through the wrong interface